Is this phrase correct: "such as the excitement and some practical skills that users can acquire from it"? Emphasis on "excitement" and "acquire"

In conclusion, while there are some advantages of playing video games, such as the excitement and some practical skills that gamers can acquire from it, these pale in comparison with the negatives, including health problems and low performance at school or work.

To my knowledge, acquire goes well with skills, but not feelings. Now, I'm not 100% sure if that's correct (it's great if you can kindly tell me in the comment), but let's assume that it is to focus on the main question:
Is the mentioned phrase correct? Normally, I would think that it isn't because acquire doesn't go with excitement.
However, acquire stands closer to skills, which it can go with. At the same time, I've read phrases like "the understanding and connection to art," in which understanding and to don't match, but since connection goes with to and it's closer to to, it's acceptable.
So, what's the answer? Thank you!
P.S. This is actually a grammar question: Given this structure: (A and B) that S + V in which (that S+V) modifies both A and B, if V only goes with B, not A, is it grammatical or not?

It might read better, if less formally, with 'get' instead of 'acquire'; the latter goes well with 'skills' but maybe less so with 'excitement'. 'Obtain' is better still.

I don't think it's a major issue, but if you're concerned try a rewrite: "While there are some advantages to gamers of playing video games, such as experiencing the excitement and acquiring some practical skills..." Also, "the understanding of and connection to art."

I’m voting to close this question because it's just nit-picking. You don't learn English by raising minor quibbles over perfectly ordinary text written by native speakers.

@FumbleFingers  There's actually a grammatical question with respect to coordination.

@TimR: I upvoted your point that There's no grammatical rule that says that gamers can acquire from it must be understood to modify "the excitement and some practical skills". But this OP is quite capable of working that out themself - and chosen not to take it into account simply in order to find fault.

@FumbleFingers  I was willing to cut some slack, assuming they'd been playing video games and their brain was still numb.

@FumbleFingers Who said it was written by a native speaker? It was written by me, and my intention was that there are two things gamers get by playing video games,  which are the excitement and the skills. However, get is informal so I want to use "acquire", but then a new problem occurs because "acquire" doesn't go with "excitement".

This problem is not rare at all; Michael and Peter actually understood it and answered on point, while you both didn't and chose to mock me instead.

This boils down to proofreading. By the way, excitement is not usually viewed as a collocatable word with practical skills.

If this is proofreading, then pretty much everything on this site is proofreading. I raised a grammar question: Given: (A and B) that S + V in which (that S+V) modifies both A and B, if V only goes with B, not A, is it grammatical or not?

Not giving an example => "give us an example so we can answer your question better". Giving an example => "you're asking for proofreading". :)

Easier to understand: excitement is not usually described as an advantage. Yes, experience excitement and acquisre skills. Peter is right. But how is this not proofreading? In fact, it's copyediting.

How is it proofreading when there is a specific grammatical concern pointed out in the post? It's a grammar point which can solve many other similar questions. I raised that grammar concern in my post and in the comment as well.


... there are some advantages of playing video games, such as the excitement and some practical skills that gamers can acquire from it ...

I add to @Michael Harvey’s comments.
Acquire excitement is indeed uncommon.  There are few hits in Google Books, and these aren’t even registered in Ngram.
Get excitement and obtain excitement are much more common.
The Ngram for the various inflections of the two verbs are as shown.
For VERB + skills, however, the results are almost the opposite although all three verbs are shown to have this collocation.
Hence we may want to adjust this part of the sentence to

... there are some advantages of playing video games, such as the excitement
gamers can get and some practical skills gamers can acquire from it ...

or simply replace acquire with get or obtain in the original sentence.


some practical skills that gamers can acquire from it

is the noun-phrase coordinated with "the excitement".
There's no grammatical rule that says that gamers can acquire from it must be understood to modify "the excitement and some practical skills".
What's worse, in my opinion, is calling "excitement" an "advantage".
Setting aside that issue, you could reverse the order and add a verb for the sake of euphony:

... such as the practical skills gamers can acquire and the excitement they experience

P.S. advantage is a comparative term, relative to something else. It is not a perfect synonym for benefit.

Yes, it does call excitement an advantage...

@Lambie  I don't understand your comment.  What do you mean by "yes"?

What's worse, in my opinion, is calling "excitement" an "advantage". The dv is NOT from me. I actually upvoted because -2 seems unfair, overall.

+1 Upvoted for suggesting a euphony.
